# Singleton in web service

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns, playframework

I create my own library to draw something...

I make a play project and set it as a web service server and call my library to provide user an image as the return value.

What I want to ask is, **should I make a Singleton class to access the library or not? Why?**

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Is there a reason for it to be accessed from a singleton? Are there performance reasons / concurrency reasons / must be only one reasons?  If not, why would you want it to be a singleton?

Comment: I want to know if there is any effect if I use Singleton or not for the performance. Or is the web service already provide the Singleton automatically?

Comment: Please tell us if there is a reason why you want/need a singleton. If someone just told you "singletons are cool", don't do it. If the server will blow up if there are two instances of your class, definitely do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Play Web Service action is a static method, so effectively your controller code is already a single executable piece of code. If you are accessing your library from your controller code (which I think you are based on your previous questions), then a Singleton is not going to make any difference apart from adding unneccessary code to your application.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Almost finish based on your previous help. Spend 3 days for this just for googling it... :D